# Invalid date time with 1 month digit instead of 2

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Oke so here's a 'cute' problem:

I've got a list with dates (and other information) these dates are filled from a Model passed to the page by my controller.

this is how i create the Table:

```
@Html.Grid(Model).Named("grid").Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Add()
                                    .Encoded(false)
                                    .Sanitized(false)
                                    .SetWidth(30)
                                    .Titled("Verzenden")
                                    .RenderValueAs(n => Html.CheckBox("Verzonden", !n.Verzonden));
                columns.Add(n => n.StartDatum).Titled("Start datum").Sortable(true).SetWidth(100);
                columns.Add(n => n.EindDatum).Titled("Eind datum").Sortable(true).SetWidth(100);
                columns.Add(n => n.Impact).Titled("Impact").Sortable(true).SetWidth(100);
                columns.Add(n => n.NotificatieType.Type).Titled("Type").Sortable(true).SetWidth(100);
                columns.Add(n => n.Omschrijving).Titled("Omschrijving").Sortable(true).SetWidth(100);
                columns.Add(n => n.Diensten).Titled("Diensten").Sortable(true).SetWidth(100);
                columns.Add(n => n.ID).Titled("ID").Sortable(true).SetWidth(100);
            }).Filterable().SetLanguage("nl")
```

I'm sorry for the dutch variables but i think you get the gist (if not lemme know and i'll change em to English)

Oke now when the selection in this list changes the onRowSelect method gets invoked:

```
$(function ()
{
    pageGrids.grid.onRowSelect(function (e) 
    {
        var startDateArr = e.row.StartDatum.toString().split(' ');
        var startDate = startDateArr[0];
        document.getElementById('startDatum').value = startDate;
    }
}
```

the `e.row.startDatum` contains the following: "25-7-2014 13:00:00"
so after the split `startDate` = "25-7-2014"

`document.getElementByID('startDatum')` refers to:

```
<input type="date" id="startDatum" />
```

The problem here is the `-7-` because it is not a valid date time (or at least not something my input accepts.

the input requires 2 digits for month (or day) so it would have to be "25-07-2014"
now i know a dirty way to fix this:

```
var dateArr = startDate.split('-');
var validDate = "";
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
if(dateArr[i].length < 2)
{
    validDate += "0" + dateArr[i] + '-';
}
else if (dateArr[i].length == 2)
{
    validDate += dateArr[i] + '-';
}
else if (dateArr[i].length == 4) // for the year and the end of the date string.
{
    validDate += dateArr[i];
}
}
document.getElementById('startDatum').value = validDate;
```

but this is dirty and i want a clean and efficient method to do this, any suggestions?

**EDIT:**

I thought the above code would work (so i did not really test it) but it still does not set my date time value (or at least the date time box still shows dd-mm-jjjj)

`document.getElementById('startDatum').value = validDate` is the correct way to do this right?

**EDIT Working but not clean**

currently have it working like so: but still, a nicer and cleaner way would still be appreciated.

```
var startDateArr = e.row.StartDatum.toString().split(' ');
var startDate = startDateArr[0];
startDate = startDate.replace(/(\b\d\b)/g, "0$1");
var dateArr = startDate.split('-');
var validDate = dateArr[2] + "-" + dateArr[1] + "-" + dateArr[0];
$('#startDatum').val(validDate);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to use Regular Expression.

Try this

```
startDate = startDate.replace(/(\b\d\b)/g, "0$1");
```

Comment: but then i'd still have to use the for loop, isn't there a way to do it without a for loop? some kind of clever command/trick i don't know?

Comment: Well you can use a regex. Something like this should work `startDate = startDate.replace(/(d)/g, "0$1");` BTW updated the answer.

Comment: that's indeed a bit better. 
But could you look at the edit, apparently i'm doing something wrong with setting the value.

Comment: Try this `$('#startDatum').val(startDate);`

Comment: apperently yyyy-mm-dd is also a requirement instead of dd-mm-yyyy

xD fixed it now, thanks for you regex but it's not working, it does not add the 0 :(

Comment: Sorry. I tested this one now and it should work `startDate = startDate.replace(/(\b\d\b)/g, "0$1");`

Comment: though not as clean as i'd hoped, it solves the problem and it's a lot shorter to write (probably a bit faster as well) so thanks, I've marked your answer as the solution.